# Do not understand different NotificationListenerService implementations

Tags: android

I'm trying to capture notifications posted in my Android 4.3

I've followed this example: http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html and it works seamlessly.

What I don't understand if I replace the NLService with my implementation which stands below, the service is never created and NLService class from example is created whenever I grant permissions from Security in Settings but my class does not.

```
public class ListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {
    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "********  Service Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    }
}
```

with Manifest.xml

```
  <service
    android:name=".ListenerService"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

Trying to know what's happening, I left NLService like my class, so it looks something like this:

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

  private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "********  Service Created");
  }

  @Override
  public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

  }
```

}

with Manifest.xml

```
  <service
    android:name=".NLService"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

And again, NLService works but ListenerService **doesn't**.

In my final attempt, I renamed ListenerService to NLListenerService, and then, it suddenly worked, printing "Service Created" when enabling the checkbox.

Can someone explain me what's happening here? :)

Comment: Do you have both correctly included in your Manifest.xml? Either that, or maybe disable/ remove one service will keeping the other since the OS might not want two NotificationListenerServices in the same app (there's really no use case for this).

Comment: I have only one included in the Manifest. The thing I don't understand is that if I prefix the Service Name with "NL" it works, but if not, it does not.

Comment: I can assure you that NL is not a necessary prefix, I have a NotificationListenerService working in my app without this prefix. When you say it only works with this prefix, are you changing both the class name AND Manifest.xml? Have you tried setting the android:name to the fully-qualified class name with package?

Comment: @Tom yep, I change manifest everytime, and tried with fully-qualified class name and without the package. None of that works until I add NL prefix. It's pretty weird. (added xml manifest in original question)

Comment: When you say it only works with the NL prefix, have you tried another arbitrary prefix? My concern is that Android doesn't want a Service named Service, even in different namespaces it might cause some confusion. Otherwise I can't see why ListenerService wouldn't be an accepted name, but try another arbitrary name like OtherListenerService.